# How to pass variable inside dom using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sorry it was a mistake to post a question about making a condition to checkbox earlier without further investigation. It seems i need to pass my variables here

```
function setsession(sessionid,action, data){
        $("#totalselection").show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'test.php',
            data:'sBorrow='+sessionid+'&action='+action,
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                var out = "<p align='center' style='text-decoration:none;color:white;'>Total Selection: "+data+"<br/>Click here to submit your request&nbsp;<a href='borrowform.php?subid=borrow' id='submitborrow' name='submitborrow' style='text-align:center;'><input type='button' value='REQUEST' id='submitborrow' name='submitborrow'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;||&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click here to clear the selection <a href='#' style='text-align:center;'><input type='button' value='CLEAR'></a></p>";

                datachecked(data, this.indexValue);

                $("#totalselection").html(out)
            }
        });
    }
```

to the DOM of other php page. NOT TO THIS URL. It was different page. Im still not clear to this ajax and i know that ajax can only send to 1 url only. However i want the data value that this ajax hold to put it inside my php echo and make if else statement using that data. Should i create one more ajax? or else? How to send data from success to my php page and received it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask

Comment: Do you wish go get a value stored withing the webclients DOM and send it to the server?

Comment: if you want to redirect to another page after the ajax i complete why do ajax at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to send your variable in ajax call. Try this simple syntax of jquery ajax call by which you can send any number of variables.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'process.php',
    method: 'post',
    data : {
        var1 : val1,
        var2 : val2

        // by this way you can send multiple variable
    },
    success : function(response){
        alert(response)
    }
});
```

process.php:

```
$val1 = $_REQUEST['var1'];
$val2 = $_REQUEST['var2'];

// use it in your own way
```

Comment: i can understand your technique. Just 1 thing. If the url is not process.php but we intend to send the variable in other php. It wont work right. Unless we create new ajax for that specific url.

Comment: Change the "process.php" as your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready(function () {
            data = {
                'name':'ys',
                'surname':'ysss',
                'pass':'123456',
                'number':5
            };
            $.post('content.php',data,function(response,status){
                if(status == 'success'){
                    $("#information").html(response);
                }
            });
```

you can send data as long as possible by writing to the 'data'